# Can anybody explain "ultimate" and "models" in this context for me, please?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In August, Clinton held a sizable lead. But Trump is the ultimate wild card. The usual models don't seem to fully capture the Trump effect. The race is now again neck-and-neck in key swing states.

The dictionary definitions of model I find do not seem to apply here:

1.a standard or example for imitation or comparison.

2.a representation, generally in miniature, to show the construction or appearance of something.

3.an image in clay, wax, or the like, to be reproduced in more durable material.

4.a person or thing that serves as a subject for an artist, sculptor, writer, etc.

5.a person whose profession is posing for artists or photographers.

6.a person employed to wear clothing or pose with a product for purposes of display and advertising.

7.a style or design of a particular product:

Source: http://money.cnn.com/2016/09/21/news/economy/us-election-economy/index.html?iid=SF_River

Comment: Look the words up in a couple of dictionaries before asking here.

Comment: ultimate: strongest possible, the wildest of wild cards. Models: expected behaviours of system in response to changes, here how we might expect the voters to respond to politicians words and actions.

Comment: @djna You're only enabling someone not to do their own research, and/or not to provide details as to their attempts to obtain possible meanings themselves.

Comment: @TRomano: I did, but I wasn't quite sure.

Comment: @haile in that case, you should link to which dictionary definitions you looked at and tell us why you were not sure about them

Comment: @AlanCarmack: Not true, Alan. I always look up what I want to ask here.

Comment: @Alan Carmack Perhaps I err by being kind, but my view was this was a non-obvious use of the word **model**, none of the three dictionaries I consulted have the meaning that applies here.

Comment: One could type `election models` into Google. Or check the major dictionaries, e.g. http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/model

Answer (score 1):

The word *model* is sometimes used to mean "ways we have used to understand or talk about this in the past."

*Model* also impiles we are not trying to shape a reality by describing it, talking about it, or attempting to predict its actions, we are just "building" oe "using a model" which may or may not be the real "end-product."  In sensitive subjects like politics it may be desirable to have this implication in order to look fair.

A "wild card" in card games often lets you do drastic things to the game, meaning if you are losing the game, you could start winning if you use a wild card.  So wild cards, when part of card games, introduce an element of unpredictability and "swing" - people who were not doing well in the game may suddenly end up the winner.  *Ultimate* is saying this property applies to the maximum possible.